# Sql Server 2012 Self Signed Certificate

Tags: asp.net, certificate, connection-string, sql-server-2012, self-signed

I have created a Self Signed Certificate and I am trying to start SQL Server 2012 with the certificate, it fails with error object of property not found. Service does not start at all.

But I removed certificate and I am able to start SQL Server.

However, I tried to connect to SQL server with Encrypt = true and Trust Certificate = true, SQL Server Client was able to connect to SQL Server. Does SQL Server automatically uses a self signed certificate from 2012 onwards?

If I set Encrypt = true and Trust Certificate = false, it gives me trust error as well. I have not installed certificate on SQL Server 2012 when I had installed it.

1. Is it a bug in SQL Server Client Library? That it is connecting with parameters Encrypt = true and Trust = true, even when there is no certificate and connection is actually not secure.
2. Does SQL Server 2012 automatically uses self signed certificate if not configured?

Comment: you should describe more detailed how you created (which properties or which parameters of `MakeCert.exe`), installed and configure the self signed certificate on the SQL Server 2012. Some tips you can find for example [here](http://thesqldude.com/2012/04/21/setting-up-ssl-encryption-for-sql-server-using-certificates-issues-tips-tricks/)

Comment: I never installed certificate before, I had self signed certificate of computer already that I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only repeat what I wrote in the comment to your question: without posting more details probably nobody can help you directly.

You can read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898) and [this](http://thesqldude.com/2012/04/21/setting-up-ssl-encryption-for-sql-server-using-certificates-issues-tips-tricks/) or [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2012/04/04/can-tls-certificate-be-used-for-sql-server-encryption-on-the-wire.aspx) for additional information which certificates can be used by SQL Server.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can find information about properties of the certificate and the private key which will be created. For the key it's very important to have `AT_KEYEXCHANGE` KeySpec option. It's difficult to change the options later (it is possible by usage `certutil.exe` with -importPFX and `AT_KEYEXCHANGE`, but it's really tricky). Self-Signed certificate which need be used for Core Signing for example should have `AT_SIGNATURE` KeySpec option in opposite. So you can't just get some unknown Self-Signed certificate and to hope that it can be used for SSL encryption. *I recommend you to use [MakeCert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) utility to create new certificate, install it and use SQL Server Configuration Manager to configure it for usage by SQL Server*.

In [the article](http://thesqldude.com/tag/makecert/) or in [another one](http://kushagrarakesh.blogspot.de/2011/10/ssl-with-microsoft-sql-server-2008.html) you will find additional information how to use MakeCert.exe to create Self-Signed certificate which can be used by SQL Server.